In Angular (Uncaught (in promise) Error: Access to storage is not allowed from this context.)
How To fix this error on the browser is error is on client they said the error is Cors related on my main.ts
main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();


main.ts From my Server side
I don't have any errors on my codes it just In the Web browser at console there's and error and this is the error my instructor said that there's should have no errors at the console at the browswer  when I inspect

What is the error text exactly? Also, what web server are you using and what are its settings?

Are you running any web extensions on your browser?  I ask as I just started seeing this error myself today, and it appears to be pointing to an extension that I am running in my Chrome browser.
